# Is a bounded subset of Z+ always finite?

Tags: analysis

Just that. Is a bounded subset of Z+ finite? I figure as such, but just want to be sure. I think it's finite because there's no way to break up a set of integers into smaller parts, and since it's bounded there will always be a countable amount of numbers, making it a finite set. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, if the set $S$ is bounded by $n$, then $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so $|S|\le n$.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: What if the bound is not specifically defined? It doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: If it is not finite than for any $n$ in it there is an element $m$ in it with $n<m$. That enables you to construct a sequence $(n_i)_i$ in it that is not bounded. Consequently the set itself is not bounded. The question is not:"what is the bound?" but:"is there a bound?" So in your own words: It doesn't matter.

Comment: That's what I figured, just was unsure. Thanks a bunch everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Call the set $S$, and assume it is bounded. Denote the upper bound by $n$. Notice that the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is the set of all such numbers, so $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$. It is a theorem that $A\subseteq B\Rightarrow |A|\leq |B|$ so we are done, since the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is *clearly* cardinality $n$. In fact, in some branches of mathematics we use this set to define what it means to have cardinality $n$.